# How to set a field as protected in yaml?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, yaml

There is a way to define an **entity properties** to **protected** in the yaml format ?

Comment: Do you mean read-only? Or what do you mean with protected?

Comment: I mean the visibility of a entity property

Comment: I dont think it is possible. But what do you want to achieve?

Comment: For example, my User entity Id attribute has to be protected for the use of FOSUserBundle. And I just wonder if it could be defined automatically into yaml instead of doing it to the Entity class after generation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things you write in doctrine yaml mapping files are metadatas. This config help you to determine how your entity object will behave with doctrine.

Properties of this object are handled by php, and cannot be configured by yaml configuration.

However, if you realy need this, you could build a cached entity generator component that will create php object in the cache and register them to doctrine. This is quite complex so I let you decide if you need it or not.

Comment: I just noticed that :( Thanks